# onload android orientation detection? (code supplied)

Tags: javascript, jquery, android

So i found some handy code on SO about checking oreintation on android devices, that worked great for loading style sheets based on the rotation of the device, but my issue now is that if the device is already "landscape" (`90 / -90` in the JS) then it ignores the rules from the code below, so i need the code below to run onload, i have attempted it but it seems i just cant get it right.

Help please ?

```
        //detect orientation change
    var supportsOrientationChange = "onorientationchange" in window,
    orientationEvent = supportsOrientationChange ? "orientationchange" : "resize";
        window.addEventListener(orientationEvent, function() {
            if(window.orientation == 90) {

                $('link[title=android]')[0].disabled=true;
                $("head").append($("<link title='android_90' rel='stylesheet' href='css/android_90.css' type='text/css' />"));
            } else if (window.oreintation == -90) {

                $('link[title=android]')[0].disabled=true;
                $("head").append($("<link title='android_90' rel='stylesheet' href='css/android_90.css' type='text/css' />"));
            } else if (window.oreintation == 0){

                $('link[title=android_90]')[0].disabled=true;
                $("head").append($("<link title='android' rel='stylesheet' href='css/android.css' type='text/css' />"));
            } else if (window.oreintation == 180){

                $('link[title=android_90]')[0].disabled=true;
                $("head").append($("<link title='android' rel='stylesheet' href='css/android.css' type='text/css' />"));
            }
        }, false);

        //check on window.load
        $(document).ready(function () {
          if(window.orientation == 90) {

                $('link[title=android]')[0].disabled=true;
                $("head").append($("<link title='android_90' rel='stylesheet' href='css/android_90.css' type='text/css' />"));
            } else if (window.oreintation == -90) {

                $('link[title=android]')[0].disabled=true;
                $("head").append($("<link title='android_90' rel='stylesheet' href='css/android_90.css' type='text/css' />"));
            } else if (window.oreintation == 0){

                $('link[title=android_90]')[0].disabled=true;
                $("head").append($("<link title='android' rel='stylesheet' href='css/android.css' type='text/css' />"));
            } else if (window.oreintation == 180){

                $('link[title=android_90]')[0].disabled=true;
                $("head").append($("<link title='android' rel='stylesheet' href='css/android.css' type='text/css' />"));
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why not just use CSS media queries?

Comment: @robertc i am using css media queries but due to the nature of this element it has more than a few size and width variables based on different screen sizes.

Comment: Hey, little nitpick with conditions ; if(window.orientation == 90) 
Don't forget the 2nd =    ;-)
And if you use jQuery, why not use it maximum : http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: lol .ready did the job, god im such a newbie :) post it as an answer so i can award it to you.

Comment: But here you only care about orientation, so why does the height and width matter? `@media all and (orientation: portrait)` and `@media all and (orientation: landscape)` would cover it.

Comment: @robertc as you seem to know about Media Queries, could you check my other post ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047884/media-queries-not-behaving-properly-on-android Thanks

Comment: I've had a quick look but I haven't had time to experiment yet, I'll have a go when I get home later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

as I said in the comment, there is a condition problem :

```
if(window.orientation == 90)
```

with the double =

Don't be too hard with yourself, *Practice makes perfect*

Edit : I'm not too sure about : `$('link[title=android]')[0]`

would have used `$('link[title=android]').get(0)` instead

Comment: @Micheal Lumbroso i have just used what you recommended (see OP) and it seems it is still not working, can you see where i've gone wrong ?

Comment: I think I've spotted another problem, see the edit (not sure though). The javascript console doesn't throw any error?