# Media queries not behaving as expected on Android

Tags: android, css, media-queries

I have 4 media queries. The 1st, 3rd and 4th work, but the 2nd one doesn't seem to activate.

Why is the 480x720 (second media query) defaulting to the first media query?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) and (orientation: portrait) { body{background:#F0F;} }
@media screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait) { body{background:#F00;} }
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) { body{background:#0F0;} }
@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 800px) and (orientation: landscape) { body{background:#FF0;} }
```

**What is expected:**

[image: 1st Media Query CSS Output]
[image: 2nd Media Query CSS Output]
[image: 3rd Media Query CSS Output]
[image: 4th Media Query CSS Output]

**What is actually happening:**

[image: 2nd Media Query fails]
[image: 1st Media Query passes]
[image: 3rd Media Query passes]
[image: 4th media query passes]

Why is the 480x720 (second media query) defaulting to the first media query?

Comment: @Kevin Peno, i have no idea what that means lol, but in theory it should just work out the box as is, but it doesn't want to ! i have tried hundreds of variations of the query but it seems to still not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need to do a device resolution detection in your media query along the lines of

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),  
       (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),  
       (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),  
       (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {  
       /* high resolution styles */  
}
```

Check [David Calhoun's excellent article on mobile best practices](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/mobile-performance-manifesto).

Answer (score 25):

I am a newbie on android and CSS.

I resolved the android not giving they real size with one line in the header of my index.html file:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

From then on, my CSS files did what I expected!

Answer (score 13):

So after doing LOADS of research i have come to this conclusion, Android phones that say they are **480px by 720px (800px or 854px)** are actually not, they use a higher screen density to make elements look larger so they actually run at **320px by XXX**, but the user can change the resolution to a lower spec if they so wish.  The reason that the media query was not working, was because the sizes were not relevant to the device in question.

If your on the SDK i changed the screen density down to 160 to accommodate 480px wide.

And i can confirm i have tested this on the SDK and 2x Handsets.

*Note: this was my personal experience it might be different for other users*

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same problems while working on a Cordova application for Android platform. Thanks to the last answer, I tried to find out where were the differences between my media query and the width of the devices screen.

I first tried :

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { ... }
```

To match devices like HTC Desire HD | Samsung Galaxy S. But I also had to do specific corrections for the Samsung Galaxy Note, so I used :

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) { ... }
```

But those resolutions, as said before, are not really used like that in the web view, the pixel density has the values changed.

So I wanted to know how many pixels in width were recognized in both DHD and SGS, and then in SGN :

```
window.innerWidth
```

For the 480px width phones, I had actually 320px recognized. For the 800px Galaxy Note, I only had 500px recognized. When I saw that, I adjusted my media queries and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

here are a few things I have found in my experience and it may be due to the higher resolution detection.
My favorite test phone is 320px(max-device-width) X 480px(max-device-width) in portrait view. But depending on which mobile browser I use the max-width can be up to 850px!!  Opera mobile uses 850px as its default max-width, even though its on a device of max-device-width 320px. Better yet; the built in Andriod browser on this device has a default max-width of 550px.  Dolphin defaults to the same max-width, 550px. I don't usually test on FireFox mobile but since it is a gecko based browser like  Opera, I wouldn't be surprised if it falls into the 850px range. Does anybody know or tested it?

i typically use a 3 condition media query when addressing  320 X 480 devices.

```
@media all and (max-width:850px) and (max-width:550px) and (max-device-width:320px) {..}
```

also i usually place this meta tag in my header on the main pageenter code here

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

The following didnt seem to help me, that's when I did some more research and figured out the info above.
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`  Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Isn't `(max-width:850px) and (max-width:550px)` doing the same thing. May as well just check greater than 550px?

Answer (score 1):

Since cell phones are an ever-growing black hole of resolution confusion, you need to tell them to identify themselves. You also need to set the scaling to 1 and take away user scaling. When I put this in my code, it does the trick for me.

Insert this snippet in the head of your HTML on the line below the `<meta character...>` tag.

```
<!-- Check Device Width so Media Queries will work -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: Solved my problem simply with a display issue that was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert all px values to em values by dividing them by 16 (so 16px will become 1 em). This makes sure, that sized have the correct proportion regardless on which font is used.
2. Add to your meta viewport: `target-densitydpi=medium-dpi`. This makes sure, that the `em`- sizes behave equally on all (most?) devices