# Media Queries Android FireFox

Tags: android, iphone, css, styles, media

Here is the link to the site I'm working on...

http://www.trenzhairstudio.ca/newlook/

Now site works perfect on a comp browser, iPhone, Android( Chrome) but in FireFox on the Andorid it appears to look different like its not reading the Media Queries.

Anyone can suggest something to make it work the same on all Android Browsers.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

try to add a device resolution detection as described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8177670/1287608 i hope it helps.