# Phonegap, problems with css styling for 480x720, 480x800 and 480x854

Tags: css, cordova, screen-size

I have been working for several days now to solve a css problem for Phonegap.

I have an App showing a map, and some control buttons. I need to set the map size so I have space for the buttoms.

It works for most of the screen resolutions, but for 480x720, 480x800 and 480x854 it doesn't work for me with three different styles. I have seen other here with semilar problems, but still have problems. The three screen resolutions pick the same style.

For instance this works for 480x720:

> @media screen and (min-device-width: 455px) and (max-device-width :
>   720px) and (orientation: portrait){ /* Styles */ }
>
> Blockquote

But then 480x800 choose the same styling.
If I then create a new styling for 480x800:

> @media only screen  and (min-device-width : 480px)  and (orientation:
>   portrait){ /* Styles*/  }

Then it works for 480x800, but 480x720 use it too.

I have tried many different things, min-device-width, max-device-width etc. Also I can't figure out why (min-device-width: 455px) works for 480x720 (found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047884/media-queries-not-behaving-as-expected-on-android/14111600#14111600))

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

This is just off the top of my head but I believe you need to do something like this:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (max-device-height: 720px) and (orientation: portrait)
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (max-device-height: 800px) and (orientation: portrait)
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (max-device-height: 854px) and (orientation: portrait)
```

Providing the correct styles for each screen resolution.