# Advice on media queries for Android devices

Tags: css, media-queries

I am currently sitting with 3 sets of images for my project.

3:2,
16:9,
16:9 high resolution

Now its time to implement these images to the correct device and I'm not really sure where to begin. There are so many android devices.. And the fact that I have 3 sets of images doesn't really help either.

What kind of media queries would you use? Would you try to target all devices or just a certain few?

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you written any code yet? Can provide inputs on top of the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Media queries not behaving as expected on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047884/media-queries-not-behaving-as-expected-on-android)