# (CSS3) Android browser doesn't load responsive CSS

Tags: android, ios, css

I'm testing my website on mobile devices, but, while on iOS it works great, on Android it doesn't: the site is zoomed in and it is unresponsive.

In my  tag I have:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

while in my CSS there is:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 979px) {
.isStuck {
   background-color: #000;
   box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
 }  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 979px) {
 #stuck_container {
  position: relative !important;
  box-shadow: none;
 }
 .pseudoStickyBlock {
   height: 0 !important;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Android stock browser changed extensively as of Android `4.4`, so if limiting your application to that version is possible, you may find it works fine, according to a [Google code issue here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67577).

I would advise targeting `handheld` rather than `screen` however, as many mobile devices identify themselves as being `handheld` devices.

```
@media handheld, screen and (min-width: 979px) { ... }
```

A previous question also suggested targeting the [device resolution instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8177670/917035).